# How to check if an element is present in an array in shell script without using loops

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have one array item1 with entries like

```
item1=($(cat abc.txt | grep "exam" |sed 's/.*exam//'|sed 's/^ *//g'|cut -d/ -f2))
```

so in this array i have below entries

abc.raml def.raml xyz.schema check1.json check2.json

now i want check for each item of this array item1, if it is present in another array  item2

so i did this using for loop

```
for i in "${item1[@]}"; do
    for j in "${item2[@]}"; do
      if  [[ $i == $j ]]
        then
                echo "file $i present in both arrays"
      fi
    done
done
```

so this loop is working fine..
but can we just get a one liner command to check if a particular element is present in another array without using another for loop inside

i tried this but it is not working

```
for i in "${item1[@]}"; do
  echo ` "${item2[@]}" | grep "$i" `
      if  echo $? == 0
        then
                echo "file $i present in both arrays"
      fi
    done
done
```

Please help me here

Answer (score 0):

Print both arrays as a sorted list, then with `comm` extract elements present in both lists.

```
$ item1=(abc.raml def.raml xyz.schema check1.json check2.json)
$ item2=(abc.raml def.raml xyz.schema check1.json check2.json other)

$ comm -12 <(printf "%s\n" "${item1[@]}" | sort) <(printf "%s\n" "${item2[@]}" | sort) | xargs -I{} echo "file {} present in both arrays"
file abc.raml present in both arrays
file check1.json present in both arrays
file check2.json present in both arrays
file def.raml present in both arrays
file xyz.schema present in both arrays
```

> to check if a particular element is present in another array

Print the array as list and `grep` the element.

```
if printf "%s\n" "${item1[@]}" | grep -qxF abc.raml; then
    echo "abc.raml is present in item1"
fi
```

When working with array items that can have newline in them, use zero separated streams.

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk .. this is working for me